# Need assistance moving files from git to git LFS, local is 15 commits ahead of remote

Tags: git

I have been using git & git lfs to keep track of things for a personal project in Unreal Engine. Initially, following a tutorial I set up my git & git LFS in such a way that git LFS didn't handle all my unreal engine files. This is now coming back to haunt me.

Several files that were small initially have now grown to a size close to 600 mb.

Examples:

> remote: error: File
>   BattleTanks/Content/Static/Landscape/Tiles/project.tmd.session is
>   592.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
>   remote: error: File BattleTanks/Content/_Levels/Battleground.umap is
>   590.67 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
>   remote: error: File BattleTanks/Content/_Levels/Battleground.umap is
>   590.51 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Recently I started playing around with creating larger levels for my game among other things. Stupidly, I only kept committing locally and since then have made considerable other changes that I am 15 commits ahead of my remote branch.

However, now the file that has been part of my commits since almost the beginning is far too large and I can't push any of my changes to the remote.

I have backed up my main folder and tried the BFG repo cleaner but I only managed to screw up my repo following some of the posted tutorials. I seem to be in a sort of predicament because I am so many commits ahead of my remote on my local machine.

So my questions are as follows:

1. What other things do I need to add to this question to help clarify? What information am I missing? I would be glad to get it - I'm not certain exactly how to structure my question.
2. How to fix? Any suggestions are welcome.
3. Should I just start fresh in a new repo and just redirect in the previous readme to the new repo?

I have pretty much stopped development until I can clean up my repo and get it right, my procrastination previously has put me in such a bind now and it's all my own fault for being lazy. I hope anyone can help me, after BFG didn't work and broke my repo locally (I had a backup) I am worried to just whack away at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with BFG repo cleaner afterall. What I did was use

> bfg --delete-files filename

then simply did

> git push -f

Before I was doing

> $ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now
>   --aggressive

because the command prompt clearly suggests to do that after. This always caused too many unexpected problems, I'm not sure why.

At any length, I wanted to close this out since I solved the problem I was having.